# numpy standard deviation does not give the same result as scipy stats standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

Scipy and numpy standard deviation methods give slightly different results. I don't understand why. Can anyone explain that to me?

Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
ar = np.arange(20)
print(np.std(ar))
print(scipy.stats.tstd(ar))
```

returns

```
5.766281297335398
5.916079783099616
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `np.std()` you are computing the standard deviation:

```
x = np.abs(ar - ar.mean())**2
std = np.sqrt(np.sum(x) / len(ar)) # 5.766281297335398
```

However, with `scipy.stats.tstd` you are computing the trimmed standard deviation:

```
x = np.abs(ar - ar.mean())**2
std = np.sqrt(np.sum(x) / (len(ar) - 1)) # 5.916079783099616
```

Note that you are computing the square root of the mean of `x` when using `np.std()` (the mean of `x` is the sum of `x` divided by the length of `x`). When computing the trimmed version you are dividing by `n-1`, `n` being the length of the array.

Answer (score 4):

It's in my mind a while ago..To get the same values

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
ar = np.arange(20)
print(np.std(ar, ddof=1))
print(scipy.stats.tstd(ar))
```

output #

```
5.916079783099616
5.916079783099616
```

My mentor use to say

> -->`ddof=1` if you're calculating `np.std()` for a sample taken from your complete dataset.
>
> ---> `ddof=0` if you're calculating for the full population

Comment: This does not answer the question of why they are not the same

Comment: I only know these `ddof` can used to balance the results...I'm not good at theory part @TCMolenaar ...I love to see if people post why?....I'm also looking for that...I've read some people saying `numpy` uses some kind of difference flavour in order to caluclate the `standard diviation`...I'm not sure...that's why I've not included reason..

Comment: see my answer below ;) it is the difference between the regular standard deviation and a trimmed standard deviation. Which is the difference in dividing by `n` and `n-1` when computing the 'mean'

Comment: Yeah see that..+1 from my side